# Error deploying Hibernate app on JBoss - No suitable driver found for jdbc

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, jboss

I have a Spring/Hibernate web application (currently working fine on Tomcat) that I am attempting to deploy to JBoss 7.1 AS.

The application all starts correctly, but if I set the Hibernate Persistence settings to create tables then I get an error on startup.

My persistence XML that was working on tomcat is as follows:

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

When I moved this PU to JBoss I started getting errors stating that it couldnt connect to the DB:

```
20:41:18,312 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-5) HHH000231: Schema export unsuccessful: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The application must supply JDBC connections
```

I googled and found a suggestion that I update my PU as follows by adding the hibernate connection details in the persistence config:

```
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy" value="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/socialcv" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I have done this, and no longer get the user errors, but now just get the following error on app startup:

```
20:35:41,791 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-8) HHH000231: Schema export unsuccessful: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/socialcv
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:604) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:190) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:173) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseExporter.<init>(DatabaseExporter.java:52) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:368) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:305) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:294) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:452) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_03]
```

Has anyone come across this or know any solution?

Comment: Did you add your driver into jboss server lib directory ?

Comment: I'm using maven to build the app, and that includes the mysql jar as a dependency - is that enough? (like i mentioned, it is working as it is on tomcat)

Comment: Maybe this value cause the problem jdbc\:mysql\://localhost\:3306/socialcv . Can you try instead this jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/socialcv .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: your DB connection URL looks incorrect. It should probably be `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/socialcv`.

Then:

Best install the MySQL driver as a module, see here: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationinAS7#Installing_a_JDBC_driver_as_a_module

Then use standalone.xml to define a data source using that driver:

```
            <datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/YourDatasourceName" pool-name="AnotherName" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/socialcv</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                    <prefill>true</prefill>
                    <use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>
                    <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>hehe</user-name>
                    <password>hehehe</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                ...
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
```

In your persistence.xml don't use the `hibernate.connection.*` properties, instead use:

```
<non-jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/YourDatasourceName</non-jta-data-source>
```

This is the de facto way to init the whole thing. Note, when using

```
transaction-type="JTA"
```

instead of

```
transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"
```

you have to change to

```
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/YourDatasourceName</jta-data-source>
```

which gives you CMT (container-managed transactions).

Answer (score 1):

Did you install the database driver?

https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationinAS7#Installing_the_JDBC_Driver

(notice the particular problems with the MySQL driver)

Best,
Anders

Comment: I have just deployed the Mysql driver jar as instructed and am still getting the error. Any other ideas?